# Apache CXF ERROR : Non-standard token 'NaN': enable JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_NON_NUMERIC_NUMBERS to allow

Tags: java, json, apache, web-services

A python client send and array like

```
"data": {"RPT_CC1_PHASE_MECH_TOT": [[1481625735000.0, NaN, 3.0], [1481625795000.0, NaN, 3.0], [1481625855000.0, NaN, 3.0], [1481625915000.0, NaN, 3.0]
```

and the apache CXF is not able to parse

```
2016-12-14 11:35:06,666 [http-nio-9092-exec-3] WARN  WebApplicationExceptionMapper - javax.ws.rs.InternalServerErrorException: org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Non-standard token 'NaN': enable JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_NON_NUMERIC_NUMBERS to allow
 at [Source: org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination$1@241e15da; line: 1, column: 401]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.processRequest(JAXRSInInterceptor.java:242)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.handleMessage(JAXRSInInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:271)
```

**how to enable this feature on APACHE CXF?**

This one seems not work

```
jsonFactory.configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_NON_NUMERIC_NUMBERS, true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found by myself:

on spring configure your custom provider

```
<jaxrs:providers>
    <bean class="my.service.ApplicationJSONProvider" /> 
</jaxrs:providers>
```

then

```
public class ApplicationJSONProvider extends JacksonJsonProvider {
    private static ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    public ApplicationJSONProvider() {
        super(mapper, BASIC_ANNOTATIONS);
        mapper.configure(Feature.ALLOW_NON_NUMERIC_NUMBERS, true);
```